# Query to Update Table using another table as information?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `Staff` and `Wages`

`Staff` Contains

```
 id,   name,     jobID,   wage
  1   Name1       2        
  2   Name2       4      
  3   Name3       1      
  4   Name4       2
```

`Wages` Contains

```
 JobID, Wage
   1    1500
   2    800
   3    1600
   4    2000
```

(There are alot more columns in the actual one I have just took the top 4)

I am missing the wages inside the `Staff` table, and the wages I need in the staff table are the rates in the `Wages` table..

So I need a query which would make the `Staff` table look like:

```
 id,   name,     jobID,   wage
  1   Name1       2        800
  2   Name2       4        2000
  3   Name3       1        1500
  4   Name4       2        800
```

An example Query which I tried was:

```
UPDATE `Staff` 
SET wage = (SELECT wage FROM `Wages`) 
WHERE jobID = (Select jobId FROM `Wages`)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to insert it into the Staff table? Why not just leave the tables normalized and do a join when you need to access the wages?

Comment: This question appears to better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just leave the tables as they are (without the `wage` column in `Staff`), in their normalized state, and run this query anytime I need the full set of (denormalized) data:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.jobID, w.wage
FROM Staff s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Wages w ON s.jobID = w.jobID
```

Answer (score 6):

In `MySQL`,

```
UPDATE Staff a
        INNER JOIN Wages b
            ON a.jobID  = b.JobID
SET a.wage = b.wage
```

In `MSSQL`,

```
UPDATE a
SET a.wage = b.wage
FROM Staff a
        INNER JOIN Wages b
            ON a.jobID  = b.JobID
```

- [**SOURCE**](http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html)