# is a generic query for verifying and fixing table possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to build a generic query that verifies and if needed corrects a whole table schema?

Example:
On my dev machine i have a sql server with some tables. I, and others, make changes to the tables and sometimes misses to notify the others about them. :/

I want to build a query that reads the dev sql tables and creates a query that i can run one another sql server and updates that table there so that they are equal. 
I cant drop the table and recreate it unfortunately. I dont want to change any of the data.

If this is to hard with sql syntax is there some tools that can do this for me? The sql tables are almost always on different machines and most likely i cant connect directly to them from the same place. So tha fixing/verifying needs to be done "offline".

Time is not of the essence, it can be a very slow query as long as it works.

update: I want to verify the sql schema and not the content of the table

update2: We are using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Please clarify whether you are changing table schema (e.g. adding columns) or data.

Comment: Seems incredibly hard to do like youve written. I suppose it is probably best to save your scripts you run against db centrally and parse them with some kind of tool so you can setup the same state on each machine.

Comment: If I've understood what you want, you might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266299/query-to-update-table-using-another-table-as-information

Comment: Agree with @DrCopyPaste. This is a process/ organisational problem. It's technically feasible to do what you want, but creating and maintaining such a thing, expecially if you throw in keys, indexes, spps, functions and dependancies, is much more of a problem, than controlling chnages to the schema.

Comment: i am not so sure it really is, i would have linked you such a program but unfortuanetly i dont have one, used to have such a tool at an old employer. the only problem you have is the script ordering and the backups/transaction logs you need...

Comment: Which database engine do you use? If it's Oracle, then PL/SQL Developer have tools you need. It is commercial product, but it's worth it's price.

Comment: There are numerous products out there that do this. It's generally called "database synchronising" or similar. It's a non-trivial task - better not to attempt it yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but not easy. This kind of tool is called a Data Dictionary, and you can write one yourself (see advice from [the Database Programmer](http://database-programmer.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/dictionary-based-database-upgrades.html)) or you can buy a commercial one, for example [RedGate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/).

Comment: Another tools would be TOAD for SQL Server.

Comment: Toad has a freeware program that does this for me apparently :) Seems to work like a charm!  http://toadworld.com/Downloads/FreewareandTrials/ToadforSQLServerFreeware/tabid/562/Default.aspx